# Проблема во срезом строки js

Tags: javascript

Есть строка 
a = '2018-10-07T10:27:52.482555+03:00'

```
alert(a.substr(0,4)) - выведет '2018'
alert(a.substr(1,2)) - выведет '01'
alert(a.substr(2,3)) - выведет '18-'
```

Моё неокрепший ум не видит логики... Почему выводит не '18', a '18-'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первый параметр - начальная позиция. Второй - количество символов

```js
var a = '2018-10-07T10:27:52.482555+03:00'

alert(a.substr(0,4)); //- выведет '2018'
alert(a.substr(1,2)); //- выведет '01'
alert(a.substr(2,3)); //- выведет '18-'
alert(a.substr(2,2)); //- выведет '18'
```